# Subscribe inside the content of observable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a dropdownlist, the value of the dropdownlist is bind in the Account.  I need another dropdown which is based on the value of the Account every time it change. Can I add subscribe to the Account so that every time it change I can add a code on it to populate the other dropdown?

```
 var riskRegisterViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Site = ko.observable();
    self.Program = ko.observable();
    self.Department = ko.observable();
    self.AuditType = ko.observable();
    self.Auditor = ko.observable();
    self.Status = ko.observable();
    self.ScheduleClause = ko.observable();
    self.AuditDateFrom = ko.observable();
    self.AuditDateTo = ko.observable();
    self.RiskRegisterArray = ko.observableArray();

    self.AuditTypeList = ko.observableArray(GetAuditType()); // This will handle the Audit Type Of the Modal dialog          
    self.ProjectList = ko.observableArray(GetProject()); // This will handle the Account Model

    self.RetrieveRiskRegister = function () {
        var riskRegister = GetRiskRegister(self.Site(), self.Program(), self.Department(), self.Status(), self.AuditType(), self.Auditor(), self.AuditDateFrom(), self.AuditDateTo());
        self.RiskRegisterArray($.map(riskRegister, function (item) {
            return new MapRiskRegister(item);
        }));
    };
    self.selectedRisk = ko.observable();
    self.selectRisk = self.selectRisk.bind(self);
    self.itemForEditing = ko.observable();

};
ko.utils.extend(riskRegisterViewModel.prototype, {
    // select an item and make a copy of it for editing
    selectRisk: function (item) {
        var self = this;
        self.selectedRisk(item);
        self.itemForEditing(new MapRiskRegister(ko.toJS(item)));            
    }
});

var riskRegisterVM = new riskRegisterViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(riskRegisterVM);
riskRegisterVM.itemForEditing.Account.subscribe(function () {
    console.log("Hello");
});
function MapRiskRegister(item) {
    var self = this;
    self.SeriesNumber = ko.observable(item.SeriesNumber);
    self.RiskRegisterEntryId = ko.observable(item.RiskRegisterEntryId);
    self.RiskRegisterTypeId = ko.observable(item.RiskRegisterTypeId);
    self.RiskRegisterType = ko.observable(item.RiskRegisterType);
    self.AuditDate = ko.observable(moment(item.AuditDate).format("MMMM DD, YYYY"));
    self.ScheduleClause = ko.observable(item.ScheduleClause);
    self.Details = ko.observable(item.Details);
    self.Account = ko.observable(item.Account);
    self.AccountName = ko.observable(item.AccountName);
    self.Department = ko.observable(item.Department);
    self.DepartmentName = ko.observable(item.DepartmentName);
    self.IsCompliance = ko.observable(item.IsCompliance);
    self.ComplianceName = ko.observable(item.ComplianceName);
    self.Findings = ko.observable(item.Findings);
    self.Recommendation1 = ko.observable(item.Recommendation1);
    self.Likelihood = ko.observable(item.Likelihood);
    self.LikelihoodName = ko.observable(item.LikelihoodName);
    self.Consequence = ko.observable(item.Consequence);
    self.ConsequenceName = ko.observable(item.ConsequenceName);
    self.RiskLevel = ko.observable(item.RiskLevel);
    self.RiskLevelName = ko.observable(item.RiskLevelName);
    self.RiskReason = ko.observable(item.RiskReason);
    self.AuditeesReason = ko.observable(item.AuditeesReason);
    self.POC = ko.observable(item.POC);
    self.POCName = ko.observable(item.POCName);
    self.TargetCompletionDate = ko.observable(item.TargetCompletionDate);
    self.IsOpen = ko.observable(item.IsOpen);
    self.Status = ko.observable(item.Status);
    self.RiskLevelCurrent = ko.observable(item.RiskLevelCurrent);
    self.StatusRemarks = ko.observable(item.StatusRemarks);
    self.DateOfCompletion = ko.observable(item.DateOfCompletion);
    self.Site = ko.observable(item.Site);
    self.SiteName = ko.observable(item.SiteName);
    self.Auditor = ko.observable(item.Auditor);
    self.AuditorName = ko.observable(item.AuditorName);
    self.RiskComputationAuditPeriod = ko.observable(item.RiskComputationAuditPeriod);
    self.Filter1 = ko.observable(item.Filter1);
    self.Filter1Name = ko.observable(item.Filter1Name);
    self.Filter2 = ko.observable(item.Filter2);
    self.Filter2Name = ko.observable(item.Filter2Name);
    self.RiskComputationCurrent = ko.observable(item.RiskComputationCurrent);
    self.RiskComputationCurrentName = ko.observable(item.RiskComputationCurrentName);
    self.IsEfficient = ko.observable(item.IsEfficient);
    self.IsRemediated = ko.observable(item.IsRemediated);
    self.IsCommitted = ko.observable(item.IsCommitted);
    self.CreatedDate = ko.observable(item.CreatedDate);
    self.CreatedBy = ko.observable(item.CreatedBy);
    return self;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you could slim down your code to just the relevant parts.

Comment: It sounds like you might be better off having your second drop down bound to a `ko.computed` that depends on the selected value (which should be bound to an observable) of the first drop down.

Comment: @MattBurland yes my second dropdown is dependent on the first dropdown
I try this code to subscribe in the account but its not working..
riskRegisterVM.itemForEditing.Account.subscribe(function () {
    console.log("Hello");
});

Comment: My point is that you don't need to subscribe if you have your second dropdown bound to a `ko.computed` that depends on a `ko.observable` that is bound to the selected value in your first drop down.

Comment: @MattBurland my second dropdown is dependent in the Account which is inside the itemForEditing observable..

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer if you removed all the non-relevant parts of your code and included (the relevant parts of) your HTML binding.

Comment: Since it looks like `Account` is also an observable, it shouldn't matter. Using a `ko.computed`, knockout is smart enough to track it's dependencies. If `Account` changes, the computed observable will be reevaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

I removed most of your other code

```
function MapRiskRegister(item) {
    var self = this;

    self.Account = ko.observable(item.Account);
    self.Account.subscribe(function(newValue){
        console.log(newValue);
    });
    return self;
}
```

Comment: @Armand.. What if I add self.DepartmentList = ko.observableArray(); in my viewmodel how can I call that inside the function MapRiskRegister(item).

Comment: @RamonCruz check the other answer it is a bit easier and should work better for your problem

Answer (score 1):

In very general terms, the way to link two drop downs is to bind the second to a `ko.computed` that depends on the selected value of the first. Something like this:

```
self.firstDropDownOptions = ko.observableArray();
self.firstDropDownSelected = ko.observable();
self.secondDropDownOptions = ko.computed(function() {
    var options = [];
    if (self.firstDropDownSelected() == whatever) {
        // populate options with whatever you need
    }
    else if (self.firstDropDownSelected() == somethingelse) {
        // population options with something else
    }
    return options;
});
```

When `firstDropDownSelected` changes, knockout will automatically reevaluate `secondDropDownOptions` because it is dependent on `firstDropDownSelected` and your drop down binding will be updated.

Your HTML might look something like this:

```
<select data-bind='options: firstDropDownOptions, 
    value: firstDropDownSelected'></select>
<select data-bind='options: secondDropDownOptions'></select>
```

In your case, I guess (without seeing your bindings) `itemForEditing` would be equivalent to `firstDropDownSelected`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of how you might do it 
http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html